# webkit-browsers (initially) renders navigation in wrong place

Tags: css, html

Hi i'm pretty new to web development and have just recently finished my first attempt at web design. I've stumbled across one issue i can't find a solution to however. In webkit-browsers one of my ul-lists (navigation) initially renders in the wrong place. When i click on one of the links it pops back in the correct position again. Full site: stenius-online.com

```
    header ul {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;  
    font-size: 145%;

}

header li {
    padding-right: 58px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your site you have a link immediately preceding your `<ul>`. Make that link `float:left;` that should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Really appreciate the answer.